# extract Text from selected nodes

Tags: xml, vb.net

VB Code , XML files.

i can't get the text of the node , a childnode of

XML look like this.

```
<...>
<OperationsSegment>

                <ID>10</ID>

                <Description>Description_1</Description>

                <Parameter>

                               <ID>Speed_1</ID>

                               <Value>

                                               <ValueString>70</ValueString>

                               </Value>

                </Parameter>

                <Parameter>

                               <ID>Speed_2</ID>

                               <Value>

                                               <ValueString>50</ValueString>

                               </Value>

                </Parameter>

                <Parameter>

                               <ID>Fan_Speed_1</ID>

                               <Value>

                                               <ValueString>30</ValueString>

                               </Value>

                </Parameter>

</OperationsSegment>
<...>
```

i have this code for now, it is supposed to look for eatch /parameter/value where the ID match the requested ID (speed_1) for example

```
Dim colNodesValParam
Dim objNodeValParam
Dim xmlDoc
Dim ID_VALUE
 

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")

xmlDoc.Async = "False"

xmlDoc.Load(MyFile)

 
ID_VALUE = speed_1


Set colNodesValParam = xmlDoc.selectNodes("OperationsSegment/Parameter[ID='" & ID_VALUE & "']/Value")

                                                                              

For Each objNodeValParam In colNodesValParam.Elements       

               
                // get  the value or text of the node “<ValueString>”                                                    

                Texte = objNodeValParam.Text
               

Next
```

i have ben trying with "objNodeValParam.Value" as well. and other XML post got me nowhere so far exept being able to entre my For Each whitch i couldnt do before.

Edit : i understand why .Value dose not work but still not able to get the text 50; 70 or 30 depanding on my ID_VALUE

Comment: This looks like it was converted from vbscript.  You should rarely use `CreateObject` in .NET code, especially with something like XML which has processing built into the framework (in two different ways no less!).  You should always either give a type to your variables or have a type established by inference; the variable declarations on this code end up as `Object` which requires late binding.  Consider using `Option Strict On` to enforce greater type safety.

Answer (score 0):

This example should help,

```
    Dim foo As XElement
    ' foo = XElement.Load("path here")
    ' for test use literal

    foo = <OperationsSegment>
              <ID>10</ID>
              <Description>Description_1</Description>
              <Parameter>
                  <ID>Speed_1</ID>
                  <Value>
                      <ValueString>70</ValueString>
                  </Value>
              </Parameter>
              <Parameter>
                  <ID>Speed_2</ID>
                  <Value>
                      <ValueString>50</ValueString>
                  </Value>
              </Parameter>
              <Parameter>
                  <ID>Fan_Speed_1</ID>
                  <Value>
                      <ValueString>30</ValueString>
                  </Value>
              </Parameter>
          </OperationsSegment>

    Dim ie As IEnumerable(Of XElement)
    ie = From el In foo...<Parameter>
             Where el.<ID>.Value = "Speed_1"
             Select el

    For Each el As XElement In ie
        Dim s As String = el.<Value>.<ValueString>.Value
    Next
```

Comment: how do i get foo = <OperationsSegment> <...></OperationsSegment> in a better way ?    because i read like 1 to 10 XML with diffent path.

Comment: @GaëtanMauger - What?  Don't understand your question.

Comment: i would have preferred foo in a path,  but i made it work in the end. thank you for trying to help me

Comment: @GaëtanMauger - Oh.  I've always found LINQ / XElement easier to use.

Comment: yeah but the guy who worked on the script before me used Path. tand this being my first XML experiance is rough (its harder to understand whats its doing compared to SQL , VB or what i code in an automaton.)

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by removing .Elements
from the For Eatch

from this :

```
Set colNodesValParam = xmlDoc.selectNodes("OperationsSegment/Parameter[ID='" & ID_VALUE & "']/Value")

                                                                              

For Each objNodeValParam In colNodesValParam.Elements
```

to this :

```
Set colNodesValParam = xmlDoc.selectNodes("OperationsSegment/Parameter[ID='" & ID_VALUE & "']/Value")

                                                                              

For Each objNodeValParam In colNodesValParam
```

made the code print the entier into parameters i can now use.